# JavaMail - Email Authentication for user registration

Tags: java, spring, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm working on a spring based web app and when a user enters his email and password for a registration **i want to a validate them and send him a email**.I have used **java mail** api and set up gmail **smtp** correctly.

Here is my register controller class.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/globalshop/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView registerModel(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        final String user_email = request.getParameter("user_email");
        final String user_password = request.getParameter("user_password"); 

        Properties email_properties = new Properties();

        email_properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        email_properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        email_properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");       
        email_properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        final String siteEmail = "**************@gmail.com";
        final String siteEmailPassword = "*************";

        Session session= Session.getInstance(email_properties, new Authenticator() {
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(siteEmail, siteEmailPassword);

            }
        });


        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(siteEmail));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(user_email));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear User,"+ "\n\n You have been successfully registerd with the gift corner!");

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        registerSucessView = new ModelAndView("test_register_succes");      
        registerSucessView.addObject("welcome", "welcome user");


        return registerSucessView;
    }

}
```

`user_email` and `user_password` are the incoming request parameters.**how can I validate them**? If the validation is successful user_email can be set to `message.setRecipients(...)`

Comment: Smooth move with the password blur, everyone can see the edits though, so you'd better change it if it was your actual password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does provide a mechanism to validate your models, as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). Personally I would recommend that you follow those guidelines so that your application makes full use of the features offered by Spring.

That being said, the most basic forms of validation for user names is to make sure that the user name is not already in your database and in some cases, certain special characters might not be allowed.

For passwords, on the other hand, there are usually some length restrictions, such as at least 5 characters. In certain situations, you can also enforce the use of letters of different casing, numbers and other special symbols. In these cases, regular expressions can be helpful. (**Note:** For this case, it is not recommended to build a single regex that will attempt to match everything).

On a completely different note, do not forget to store your passwords as hash values, and then, when the user logs on, you compare the value of the hash of the password which the user has entered with the hash that you have already in your DB.

Comment: Please note that just comparing naked hashes is not anywhere near "secure" for a good amount of years now, you'd want to generate some salt which you store in the session and add it to the password after hashing and then hash it again before even sending it over the network.

Comment: @CeilingGecko: I agree with you. I did not want to delve into much detail since hashing was outside of the scope giving this question.

Comment: No worries, wasn't aiming that at you personally per se, just wanted to add a little note for the avid readers of the future.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the user's email address doesn't help you if you don't know what server the user is using.  There are ways to figure that out in many cases, but you may not have access to that server even if you could figure it out.  The only reason to ask for the password is because you want to log in to the user's email server as if you were that user.  Hope the users trust you!

If you really just want to know that the user's email address is valid so that you can send email to that user, the only real way to know is to send a message to the address and ask the user to do something (e.g., visit a URL on your server) if the message is received.

You'll find additional information in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr).